# Can i stop EC2 instance which is using auto scaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I have created ec2 instance and it's part of the auto scaling group and i want to stop this instance so i can save money while this server being not used.Whenever i want to use this server that time i can start the instance.

Comment: Did you tried scheduled scaling for ASG? [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html)

Comment: Sadly you can't stop it while in asg. You have to detach it first from asg

Comment: if i'll detach instance then i can attach again the same instance to the asg ? @Marcin

Comment: I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 3):

AutoScaling Group is able to take care of this process for you.

You can change the size of the group [manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-manual-scaling.html), or you could [schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html) custom configurations to scale-up or scale-down as per your needs.

This is all supported through AWS APIs, so you can do this through AWS Console or automating the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Instances in ASG can't be stopped. If you want to stop one instance you have to [detach it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/detach-instance-asg.html) from ASG. When you are ready to start it, you can [attach it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-instance-asg.html) again.

But really, you should reconsider how you use ASG. Detaching and re-attaching instances from ASG is meant for mostly troubleshooting purposes, not something you do regulatory just to save cost. Its better to set minimum and desired capacity of ASG to 0 if you don't want any instance in it.